# MYSQL summary query

Tags: mysql

Newbie want to enhanced his sql queries, hope someone guide me.

I have table tblIN which will stored a record of all incoming records, and table tblOUT which will stored all outgoing records. Now i want to show a result from tblIN that has a balance column and a summarized of total out_qty from tblOUT.

Below is the table structure

**tblIN**

`id    code   in_qty
 1      A      10
 2      B      20
 3      A      5`

**TtblOUT**

`id     code   out_qty    in_id
 1       A        2         1
 2       A        4         1 
 3       A        1         3
 4       B        15        2
 5       B        3         2
 6       B        1         2`

**Result**

`in_id    code   in_qty    out_qty    balance
  1       A       10        6           4 
  2       B       20        19          1
  3       A        5        1           4`

At this moment, my approach is to queries tblIN with 2 empty column

`select id,code,in_qty,0 as out_qty,0 as balance from tblIN`

After get the result, i will loop through all the result and do another queries to find the total out_qty and do some calculation to get the balance.

I believe if it just contains some small records then i wouldn't a problem in performance, but if i have a huge records then i believe it will caused a performance problem.

So what i am looking for is a simplified and effective queries to do the job above without any looping.

Comment: Try the query below
`select id,code,in_qty,(select sum(out_qty) from tblout where in_id=tin.id group by in_id)'out',(in_qty-(select sum(out_qty) from tblout where in_id=tin.id group by in_id)) as balance from tblin tin`

Comment: how about the null the value from the select sum?

Comment: use ifnull condition like `ifnull(sum(out_qty),0)`

Comment: can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: posted it as answer with null checking condition applied in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query below.

```
select id,code,in_qty,(select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) from tblout where in_id=tin.id group by in_id)'out',(in_qty-(select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) from tblout where in_id=tin.id group by in_id)) as balance from tblin tin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL `LEFT JOIN` and `CONCAT` for code. Then for the balance, you can do this

```
SELECT b.in_id, 
       CONCAT(a.code,', ',b.code) as code, 
       a.in_qty, 
       b.out_qty, 
       (a.in_qty-b.out_qty) as balance 
       FROM tblIN a 
       LEFT JOIN tblOUT b 
       ON a.id=b.id
```

Comment: using INNER JOIN will only show records that recorded in both table right? what if no record in tblOUT? the record in tblIN won't show.

Comment: Okay so use `LEFT JOIN`. This will prioritize the value in first table. Showing it's value even it has no match records on another table.

Comment: just try your queries, found out that using left join will duplicate the records if found more then one record in right table, while i want the  right table is summarized.

Comment: Ok. Add `GROUP BY(a.id)` at the end

Comment: the group by works perfectly, i dont understand why using `CONCAT`, it will just concatenate the code from a and b right?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  id,
  code,
  in_qty,
  (select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) from tblout where in_id=tin.id group by in_id)'out',
  (in_qty-(select ifnull(sum(out_qty),0) from tblout where in_id=tin.id group by in_id)) as balance 
from tblin tin
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that query such that others can learn from it